# How to create circular list view of items in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a view where items view will be in circular round. Here i am sharing my image to describe my requirement.

The number of items will be dynamic.

[image: circular items]

Can anyone suggest library for this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check this library : [WheelView](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView)

add dependency to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.lukedeighton:wheelview:0.3.1'
}
```

add custom view to your xml

```
<com.lukedeighton.wheelview.WheelView
    android:id="@+id/wheelview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:wheelColor="@color/grey_400"
    app:rotatableWheelDrawable="false"
    app:selectionAngle="90.0"
    app:wheelPosition="bottom"
    app:wheelOffsetY="60dp"
    app:repeatItems="true"
    app:wheelRadius="276dp"
    app:wheelItemCount="14"
    app:wheelPadding="13dp"
    app:wheelItemRadius="43dp"/>
```

set adapter in java code

```
wheelView.setAdapter(new WheelAdapter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(int position) {
        //return drawable here - the position can be seen in the gifs above
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return the count
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. i will check it.

Comment: nice library.. and meanwhile i also found one more good library... https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout

Comment: in WheelVIew library i cant set the my own view items. only image drawables can be set to wheel adapter.  how to set View items items in it. Because i need to set textview values also.

Comment: Hi @HimanshuMori, Have you found any way to do that? I am facing the same issue.